# How to turn off Apps corner in Lumia Denim

Tags: lumia-denim-update

While I browsed through new options in settings, I found Apps corner which provides selective app to be on your home screen. I opted for this option and found that I could not get any options to turn off or return to earlier home screen.

Please suggest how to turn off Apps corner or roll back to home screen. please assist

PS: I have recently updated to Lumia Denim - India

Comment: Do you mean "Apps Corner" ?

Comment: @Neil Yes you are right. Edited question, thanks

Comment: its not working ...
o get out of Apps Corner, press and hold the Power button, and then swipe right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get out of Apps Corner, press and hold the Power button, and then swipe right. You can also pin Apps Corner to the home screen so you don't have to dig through the phone settings.